# Debugging an Android application

Tags: android, debugging, redpin

I try to use an open source indoor positioning application, [Redpin](http://redpin.org/).

Some images that i upload before is presented with some ui classes.

But i found out that some dialogues can not be seen and after dialog problem the image on view  become corrupted.

There is nothing red or orange in LogCat, or console of running Android.

The view and activity classes are on below links:

https://sourceforge.net/p/redpin/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/RedpinAndroid/src/org/redpin/android/ui/mapview/MapView.java

https://sourceforge.net/p/redpin/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/RedpinAndroid/src/org/redpin/android/ui/MapViewActivity.java

As a summary my question is:

except LogCat, where can i look at about what is happening when the image become corrupt?

Comment: what do you mean by image become corrupted?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch  i mean image becomes black and has some points with rainbow colors on it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is using regular breakpoints to debug your code. This will at least help you figuring what messes up your image. Maybe this is way to obvious but I guess worth mentioning anyway.

In android their is also a tool called Hierarchy Viewer that for debugging your UI. It is mostly for optimization but can also be used for finding errors in your UI. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer.